# call js method only on wordpress shortcode page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gulp

I want to call a js method only that page contains the same shortcode I passed on another page of shortcode that function should not execute....

for example, I have two shortcodes on different pages. when I go to the 2nd page then 1st-page shortcode method fired and return an error in console log that some ID is not found...

have a look a code

Note I'm using Gulp

my first code

1st shortcode js

```
class EmiCalculator {
//construct
constructor() {
    this.calculateEMI();
    this.events();
    this.footerTitle();
}
```

this.calculateEMI();
return error when I go to other TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

so I want when I got another page I want this.calculateEMI(); method not fire...

Comment: Maybe you can juste check if your element exist on the page before running calculateEMI method

Answer (score 0):

You can register a js script file like-

```
wp_register_script( 'js-name',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'assets/js/yourfile.js',array ('jquery'),'',true );
```

and after that you can enqueue in your shortcode function.
you can add like this-

```
function shortcode() {
wp_enqueue_script('js-name');
//code
}
```